# IntelliJ IDEA Alt+Scroll Wheel stopped working in Windows

Tags: java, intellij-idea, shortcut

There was a feature that IntelliJ added maybe 8 months ago, where if you were in a method, you could click on a particular variable, then hold the Alt key and use the scroll-wheel of the mouse to jump through all the occurrences of this variable in that scope. I found this feature very useful, when analyzing large blocks of legacy code.   It appears one of the more recent releases of IntelliJ IDEA broke this feature.  (Or maybe it was moved to another shortcut?)

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-194787

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @CrazyCoder, Yaroslav Bedrov's suggestion worked, I went to Settings | Keymap,  searched for "Go to next/previous highlighted element usage" actions, and manually configured Alt+MouseWheelUp,   Alt+MouseWheelDown.   Now it's working again.    I wonder if this setting will persist after the next IDE update...

Comment: setting appears to be persisting throughout multiple releases, so that's great

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1, the settings are called "Next Highlighted Usage" and "Previous Highlighted Usage"